# how to update progress bar accordingly when we are executing a method(not downloading a file) in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have already implemented downloading a file with asynctask with progress bar showing the correct progress in the download of that particular file. In this case the size of the fileto be downloaded is known before hand.

But now i want to do show the progress in progress bar while performing a particular function say

```
methodLongTask();
```

What I was doing was just updating the system clock from 0-100 like this

```
while(myProgress<100){
            myProgress++;
            publishProgress(myProgress);
               SystemClock.sleep(100);
           }
```

I think this was merely doing the progress update from 1-100 only

this `methodLongTask()` may inturn call its sub methods which may result in say (copying couple of files, unzipping a zip file, rezipping it etc). My question is that is there any correct way to show the excact progress updation of the execution of my `methodLongTask` with asynctask.

Comment: you can increase a static count as your method progresses and let your progressBar know

Comment: @PankajNimgade can you provide me with an example link